# Application working but ad does not show up?

Tags: java, android

Here is my MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.ads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my code from xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The application works fine just the ads don't show up. Is it because i have bot supplied a AD_UNIT_ID or is anything else wrong like setting adview to wrap_content becuase since it has nt loaded height would be zero. Is very very slow internet connection a reason?
[image]

There is white space on both sides of ad.How do i cover it with ad

Comment: If the internet is not working, then it could be the problem.

Comment: adView.setApid("154050");  This is my appid replace it with your own appid and hope it's worked :)..also in your xml file also set your appid on this line ads:adUnitId="yourappid".

Comment: So i should just replace MY_AD_UNIT_ID with 154050.

Comment: 154050 this is my google ads id,your google ads id will be different.

Comment: I have not submitted any app so i don't have any id will there be a problem if i use yours while testing my application.

Comment: yes u can use for a testing purpose but i think it will not worked..

Comment: also have u add google ads permission on android menifast file?

Comment: The ads are showing up but it leaves empty space on sides. Is there any way to fit ads completely in width.

Comment: yes..in your xml file set the width of your ads  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: let me know if your issue is reolved.

Comment: That did not help. It was in center now but did not cover complete width.

Comment: i test ur xml file on my side and it's working fine..

Comment: Is it covering width completely. I am attaching a pic in my question to show how it looks on my mobile.

Comment: ok please attached the picture..and also mentioned it that how would u like to display :)

Comment: i have edit my ans plz checked..

Comment: have u seen my edited ans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(see complete discussion below the posted question)
just copy that xml file and paste it in your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this and hope now it's worked:

```
package com.example.ads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int BANNER_AD_WIDTH = 320;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

int placementWidth = BANNER_AD_WIDTH;
adView.setWidth(placementWidth);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

Comment: it did not work. This is exactly what i have already written.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to give `"MY_AD_UNIT_ID"` to show ad. Check you project log-cat. some time ,it do not show ad because ad sdk show message in log `"NO inventory to show ad"`

So, put you `Ad UNIT ID` and check `log cat` for see problem.

Thanks